# Diophantine equation $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{3}{5}$

Tags: diophantine-equations

I'm trying to solve the diophantine equation $\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=\frac{3}{5}$  for all $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$. 
I did this. Since that the diophantine equation is symmetric, we can suppose that $x\leqslant y \leqslant z$ so $xy \leqslant 5z$ then x+y \leqslant 1$ e $x<0$. But I can no go further. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are $x,y,z$ positive?

Comment: This might help -- it's a little bit simpler than your question but might give some guidance: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403036/natural-number-solutions-to-fracxyxy-n-equivalent-to-frac-1x-frac-1y

Comment: $x,y,z\in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Would $(1,10,-2)$ be a valid solution, then?

Comment: Yeah, this is ONE solution. I'm trying to found all integer solutions. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Some autors has called these equations “Egyptian”. You have actually a cubic equation of three variables so it is not so easy.

Comment: Hi Elaqqad, if you are not wrong (what I believe without proof) this could be useful really

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake $$(x(3z-5)-5z)(y(3z-5)-5z)=(5z)^2$$

Comment: The problem with this factorization is that $z$ is a variable so we don't have informations about its prime factors

Comment: The solution there.     http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450280/erdös-straus-conjecture/831870#831870

Comment: $(4,4,10)$ is an obvious solution.

Comment: All solutions for $|x|,~|y|\le10^3$ can be found [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QBGrS.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may suppose that $0\lt |x|\le |y|\le |z|$. Then, since one has
$$\frac 35=\left|\frac 1x+\frac 1y+\frac 1z\right|\le \left|\frac 1x\right|+\left|\frac 1y\right|+\left|\frac 1z\right|\le \frac{3}{|x|},$$
one has
$$|x|\le 5\Rightarrow x=-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5.$$
This should make it easier to solve the equation.