# Elementary number theory and quadratic

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Find the value(s) of $a$ for which the equation

$ax^2-4x+9=0$

has integral roots(i.e. $x$ is an integer).

My attempt:

By hit and trial I am getting answer as $a=\frac{1}{3}$. No information about nature of $a$ is given.

Comment: I think that there is also another value for $a$: $-1/4$. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ is a root then $a=(4n-9)/n^2$. It follows that the roots are $n$ and 
$$\frac{9n}{4n-9}=2+\frac{n+18}{4n-9}.$$
Now if $(n+18)/(4n-9)$ is an integer then $-2\leq n\leq 9$ (because $|n+18|$ has to be greater or equal to $|4n-9|$. By checking, we find that it is an integer for $n=2,3,9$. The corresponding values for $a$ are $-1/4$ and $1/3$.

Answer (score 1):

If the roots are $p$ and $q$, then

$$ p+q = \frac{4}{a} $$
$$ pq = \frac{9}{a} $$

Dividing gives

$$ \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = \frac{4}{9} $$

If you can find all integer solutions to this equation, you can plug in to get the possible values for $a$.

It's not to hard to do an exhaustive search over the small values of $(p,q)$ until you reach the point where it's obvious nothing larger could be a solution.

---

Alternatively, you can boil down the roots to a single integer, e.g

$$ (p+q)^2 = \frac{16 + 18 a}{a^2} $$

so the problem boils down to finding $a$ such that $a^2 \mid (16 + 18 a)$.

(here, divisibility means that the r.h.s. is an integer multiple of the l.h.s.)

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403036/natural-number-solutions-to-fracxyxy-n-equivalent-to-frac-1x-frac-1y

Answer (score 1):

I propose a graphical understanding of this question:

Consider it as looking for the intersection points of these two curves

$$\cases{y=4x-9\\y=ax^2}$$

- The first one is a fixed straight line on which we define points with integer abscissas $P_k(k,4k-9) \ \ (k \neq 0).$
- the second one is a variable parabola with an "opening" coefficient $a$ we have to constrain in order that the parabola passes through the different points $P_k$. And this is possible for every values of $k$ by equating the ordinates (for all $k \neq 0$)

$$a k^2 = 4 k -9 \ \ \ \Longleftrightarrow \ \ \ a=\dfrac{4k-9}{k^2}$$