# Equation $ 1/x + 1/y = 1/n^p $ has $ 1009^{2018} $ natural (x, y) solutions. n is natural number, p is a prime and $ p<10000 $. Find values of p.

Tags: number-theory

I have a few observations:
if y = a, x = b is a solution then y = b, x = a is also a solution.
$1009^{2018}$ is uneven so x = y is a solution.
Could you give me some hints how to continue solving this problem?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4099489/determine-the-smallest-n-such-that-frac1x-frac1y-frac1n-has-a9) for a solution method.

Comment: The problem is outdated. It is already $2022$.

Comment: Thanks, I solved it.